# iPhone Keypad Skipping,when using Text field/button

Tags: iphone

How to skip keypad through Button Action Event in the place of RETURN button on Keypad.
I changed attribute for keypad also but i'm not getting the thing .

Comment: Could you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the `resignFirstResponder` selector to your Input field (UItextView...)

ex : `[myTextView resignFirstResponder];`

---

Apple doc for UITextView look at **Managing the Keyboard** in the overview section :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Apple doc for `resignFirstResponder`
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder